# lot of select requests

Tags: php, mysql

Im running an application that require lot of select count when on heavy traffics time, and I want to limit that, Im sure there is a technique to story the select query result on a temp variable the get it without accessing the DB, and update that value every x second that will for sure reduce overall load time.

here is the function call:
return $this->getOnlineNow($user_code);
That line is called every time a visitor view my application widget, you can imagine the huge stress on the DB on heavy traffics.

Comment: yes, there's plenty of methods of cacheing such information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try caching the data which you get from select statement.

But, it will not help if you try to update that data frequently as you said:

> the select query result on a temp variable the get it without
>   accessing the DB, and update that value every x second

You need to make sure first, you are calling the database lesser no of times in this interval, to what it is been accessed currently .To update the temp table after x second interval means you need to connect the database every x seconds which adds with the overhead of accessing the database at present. This may make things even worse as they are currently.

You can find some basics/quickstart on caching [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-qc.quickstart.caching.php) and may google help you.

Comment: Im planing to update the value every 10 second, and thats great comparing to a query that run 100 time on one second !
So how to do that, as I said Im not a programmer :)

Comment: Mayukh R, I think you didnt get my idea, whats best a select from DB that run 20 time on one second or just one time every 10 second !

Comment: Yes, got your point, and this is true, you need to update the cached table anyway. I totally got the frequency thing wrong from the explanation..anyway, added a link on basics of caching and here is a very old article which describes it in a nut shell: http://benmetcalfe.com/blog/2005/12/mysql-database-caching-in-php/

Comment: Thanks ! I'll read that right away, wish I'll understand something :)